# Soldering back the disconnected wires from the charger board

Tags: power-supply, charger, electrical

The attached link images are the front and back photo of the board inside my charger. This charger is used to charger my son's toy car. Unfortunately, the wire soldered on this chip got disconnected. Now I have 2 wires red and black. Kindly help me in finding the exact location, where these 2 wires should be soldered. Thank you all in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the rectangle called USB with 4 holes in a row.

Of those 4 holes red goes in the hole closest to edge of the board and black in the one at the other end.

How I decided that.

It's a charger circuit board and the designer designed it to take a USB socket for output (or instead a 2 pin socket like JST).
the 4 holes ans two slots are the footprint (board pattern) for common USB A sockets. also USB is printed on the board,

The two holes where the wire goes are the power pins of a USB socket.
In the photo of the underside I could see the broken ends of the wire outlined in the solder, so I was failly sure the wire had come from there.

In the photo of the top I looked at the nearby capacitor and saw negative next to one pin (and connected to it on the underside), so that one is negative and the other is positive. (I could have looked this up on-line, but there was enough in the photo).

Red is almost always positive and black is almost always negative so I said to connect the wires that way.

If the wires had been pink and purple I would not have been able to guess which way round to connect them.

Comment: Thanks. Let me solder and check

Comment: I have connected the wire and it is working fine.Thank you.  Can you please explain me the logic. ?

Comment: I have added details

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Will it be a problem, if I interchange the red and black wire ? The 2 rods that comes out of the charger (which will be inserted inside the plug point) can be interchanged and it works fine.

Comment: in most case yes, most devices require that the electric current flows in a certain direction, many devices will be damaged by a reversed connection, othes just won't work, or wont work correctly.